# How to show a "large text" SMS preview? (e.g. for confirmation code)

Tags: notifications, sms

Some online services send you a SMS with a confirmation code (e.g. when requesting a new password). When sliding the notification window (from up to down) in some cases I can see that the actual code is the only information shown (and it's **very large**), and the complete SMS is shown only if you tap on the notification.

Initially I thought it was simply a result of putting the code as the first token of the SMS body (like "*12345 is your code*"), but I tried sending an SMS to myself and it seems that is not enough.

Is there some SMS setting that I can use?

My device is *Huawei Honor 8* and my OS is Android 7.0 (EMUI 5.0.1)

Comment: I am not aware of any setting that can help either on Marshmallow or Oreo (please [edit] your question to mention device and OS details). I use [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ram.chocolate.otphead) that shows the code information on screen till dismissed

Comment: Can you give an example of the place where they send you such a code? Any verification code I get are part of the text and I don't see it in larger